# DJI-Mobile-SDK/position control

Tags: dji-sdk

I am useing DJI Mobile SDK to crtate an APP by Android Studio now.I want to know how to use the GPS signal of the aircraft and the phone to realize position control. Is there any API in the DJI Mobile SDK I can use?

Comment: And I don't want to use FollowMeMission because there is a altitude limit in FollowMeMission

Answer (score 0):

You may follow this sample to run simple higher-level GPS position control https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/GSDemo.html

If you stop at some waypoint, it can automatically hold the position. It is a simple recreation of the DJI pilot app waypoint planning.

For low-level GPS position control requires a higher understanding of the system. This usually allows interesting applications such as allow drone to follow some person or precision landing to some mark or circle around some tower.  There is not much open-source implementation available on the internet. You have to search in the MSDK for the API for some basic control and you also need to have deep understanding in the field that you are trying to achieve e.g real-time object detection, low-level control framework, Visual-Inertial SLAM etc

[image]